# How to add "responsive.details.display" option for Shiny application?

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, modal-dialog, responsiveness

I would like to improve the responsiveness of Shiny application by adding  "responsive.details.display" option for 'renderDataTable' functions. As you know, the code should look like

```
   "datatable(dataframe, extensions = c('Responsive'),  ...)".
```

Here is an example for desired outcome https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/bootstrap-modal.html.

Will be glad to get your advice and code examples how to do it?

Comment: This is just to add 'responsiveness' to DT. So is that what you're trying?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I know how to add 'Responsive' tags to DT. The issue here is how to code functionality by given web address "Bootstrap modal". The concrete piece of code will be very useful.